# IE10 prevent selection on elements at onTouch(-ms-touch-action)

Tags: scroll, touch, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11, windows-rt

I tried to make something like in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/WM583/20/ on Windows RT with IE10.

The problem is, that the touched element always gets selected on touch, which looks bad. I tried:

```
-ms-touch-select:none;
-ms-user-select:none;
user-select:none;
```

But it still gets selected. Does anybody know how to prevent the selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

Special meta tag

```
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
```

and also the following style

```
a:active{background-color:transparent !important;}
```